# How to get rid of security exception?

Tags: .net, security, exception, full-trust

I start a .Net server side program on my local workstation, but soon it throws a security exception. I searched the web for answers, but no quick fix was found / worked. I just want to run my program. How do I get rid of the exception? I fully trust the program, because its mine.

Edit: Oh, yes, I do run the program from a mapped folder that is mapped to my own local drive for the sake of clarity of folder structures. Thanks for the answers, I try tomorrow to run it directly from my drive.

Edit: When I use directly my drive, it works.

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: Its probably because he isn't running from a trusted location, so CAS is blocking some of his BCL calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET 3.5 SP1 has better support for running applications on the local intranet.](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/12/fulltrust-on-the-localintranet.aspx)

If you can't target 3.5 SP1, you can map the share you're running the application from to a local drive and [use CasPol to set that mapped drive to a fully trusted location.](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary measure, you can type...

```
caspol -s off
```

...and all .NET Code Access Security is suspended (until you hit < enter >).