# CAS: Running exe from intranet

Tags: .net, security, cas

Before I get flamed and down-voted without mercy, my company will not allow the install of .NET3.5 on non-dev machines yet (others are currently on 3.0).

I have a managed exe on network share that needs to be able to run from there.  This is a common problem with pre-.NET3.5SP1, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.  I have read  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197835/how-to-get-rid-of-security-exception), as well as, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx), in addition to the MSDN CAS articles (which is like trying to read and understand a EULA).  I cannot seem to solve this problem.

I've tried signing it; along with other suggestions found in the articles.  The only way I've found to get it to run from the network is to make it a click-once application and publish it; which is unacceptable because it creates a bunch of different files in the published directory (which confuses our less-than-technical users) and creates entries in the Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel.

I'm just a dev, so I don't have rights to set/alter machine policies and such.  Can anyone give me step-by-step instructions (or point me to a easy-to-read site) on what needs to be done to enable this thing to run from the network?  Is it even possible without setting machine/domain security/software policies (which I don't have access to)?

**Edit**
Ok... I expected to get voted down; however, it would be really nice if people would explain why they down-voted.  This is a serious question that many people seem to be having a problem with; and almost no one seems to know how to fix.

Comment: You need the help of somebody who can do this. Software deployment is easy to do on a domain.

Creating entries in the Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel is a good thing.

Comment: Osama, normally I would agree with you, but in this instance it's really not a good thing.  I'm not truly installing anything on their machine, so the Add/Remove entry is kind of a 'phantom' entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre 3.5 and without access to the machine itself or machine/domain policy, I think you're out of luck.

The brute force approach is to go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > MS .NET Framework X.X Wizards > Adjust .NET Security on each machine and set the security level for the Local Intranet zone to FullTrust. The security risk with this approach is that now you're trusting *all* .NET code that's available on your intranet, which may not be what your organisation wants.

The more surgical approach is to give your .NET assemblies a strong name by signing them with your development team's private key (which can be generated by .NET). Then do a once-only install of a policy on your users' machines that trusts all assemblies signed with your team's key. Now all of your team's .NET assemblies will be fully-trusted no matter where they're physically located.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was afraid this might be the answer.  I tried signing the assembly (clicking the sign assembly checkbox and creating the key), but that didn't work.  I'm assuming because of the policy issue.  I'll see if I can work with the networking department and get them to do that.

Comment: Hopefully they will have push technology to roll-out the policy to users' machines automatically, perhaps overnight.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an unmanaged bootstrapper that copies your .net code locally and launches it.  Or you can use click once and create a shortcut in another directory to hide you other files.